# SignalR: how to survive accidental page refresh

Tags: signalr

Imagine there is a chat web app between two browser clients using SignalR. What is the best approach to survive accidental F5 hit done by one of the client?

[Here](http://www.kevgriffin.com/maintaining-signalr-connectionids-across-page-instances/) is described the strategy using cookies together with custom SignalR IConnectionIdFactory. But the author of the article says *"The SignalR team doesn’t recommend this action"*. So what is the recommended architecture?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can map the temporary connection id to a permanent user id/name (which might be stored in your DB) when the client connects. See the [ShootR example](https://github.com/NTaylorMullen/ShootR) which does this (last time I checked, at least).
For example, you could keep a ConcurrentDictionary of objects representing users that you track active users with and associate them with their connection ids in `OnConnected` (and revert this in `OnDisconnected`) similar to this:

```cs
private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, User> Users 
    = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, User>();

public override Task OnConnected() {   
    string userName = Context.User.Identity.Name;
    string connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;

    var user = Users.GetOrAdd(userName, _ => new User {
        Name = userName,
        ConnectionIds = new HashSet<string>()
    });

    lock (user.ConnectionIds) {   
        user.ConnectionIds.Add(connectionId);
    }

    return base.OnConnected();
}
```