# No access to the Session information through SignalR Hub. Is my design is wrong?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I've just discovered you can't access the current session within the SignalR Hub.

Simplified my scenario: I've tried to write a chat.

The name of the current user was kept within the Session.

I've used SignalR to update (a group of connections) about every new message.

Now I see that I can't access the name of the current user through the hub.

I guess there might be some workarounds, but is that implement my design was wrong?

Should I've not used SignalR for that purpose? Or should I not use `Session` in this way?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You shouldn't use Session with SignalR (see [SignalR doesn't use Session on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854663/signalr-doesnt-use-session-on-server)). You identify logical connections by their connection id which you can [map to user names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20521466/2001735).

The underlying problem is that [access to SessionState is serialized in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479041.aspx) to ensure state consistency, so each request to the hub would block other requests. In the past, limited read-only access (I assume (but can't confirm since the gist is gone) by setting [EnableSessionstate to read-only](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.pagessection.enablesessionstate.aspx), which prevents the locking problem I described) was possible, but [support for this was dropped](https://gist.github.com/davidfowl/4692934). Also see [various other places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768838/signalr-serversentevents-on-windows-server-2008-with-iis-7-post-request-taking-t) where the SignalR team made similar statements. Lastly: there's a statement in the official [documentation](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/troubleshooting-and-debugging/troubleshooting) about `HTTPContext.Current.Session`.

Comment: But I already have some information within the session, from normal requests. Should I not use session *at all* ?

Comment: No, you shouldn't use it at all with SignalR. You'll need to find another way of sharing the necessary data - either cache it server-side with your user data, pass it into your hub methods or [set state on your hub](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server), depending on the nature of the data.

Comment: Thanks!.. Not disrespecting your knowledge, but can you please give some reference to that? I just want to be sure

Comment: @Letterman I added more detail to my answer, as well as a few links

Comment: @LarsHöppner So am I right to assume the 'correct' way to handle this is keeping connectionID's in session?

Answer (score 14):

You could send values from client to server hub via Query String.

Before the `$.connection.hub.start()` method you could add something like this:

Client JS Code:

```
// Replace "some value" with the session value or anything you want
$.connection.hub.qs = { "Name": "some value" };

$.connection.hub.start()...bla bla bla
```

On the server side on the Hub you could use this in any method:

```
string ClientValue= Context.QueryString["Name"].ToString();
```

I did not test with sessions, but of course on client side you could be as awesome as you can.

Answer (score 2):

I was in a situation where I couldn't use the User/Identity because the session hadn't been authenticated yet so I just used the actual session cookie value.

```
 [HubName("headerHub")]
 public class HeaderHub : Hub
 {
    static HeaderHub()
    {
        EventManager.CartUpdated += Update;
        EventManager.LoggedOut += Update;
        EventManager.LoggedIn += Update;
    }

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        var group = Context.Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Value;
        Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, group);
        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    private static void Update(object sender, SessionEventArgs e)
    {
        var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<HeaderHub>();
        hubContext.Clients.Group(e.SessionId).onUpdateHeader();
    }
}
```

I am sure someone will find something wrong with this solution and if so feel free to comment because I would like a better way to accomplish tying a session to a set of clients to notify.

Comment: I m new to SignalR, I m also in situation where I need to identify SignalR clients based on some custom id where I thought of using  ASP.Net session id. I m also interested in knowing if there is any flaw in these design. Will try out this now :)

Comment: I tried to do this but I found that the session ID kept on changing for every request.  The session ID isn't persisted until the session is accessed (IE data is stored for the user) [This answer explains why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2874174/894792).

Answer (score 1):

One the best approach is to use Cookie instead of session. because as mentioned above , You can not use session . so When user login to your system, put its unique identifier(such as username) in cookie . then work with cookie where ever you want access  session . such below...

```
  public class CustomUserIdProvider : IUserIdProvider
    {
        public string GetUserId(IRequest request)
        {
           return request.Cookies["ODPUserID"].Value;
        }
    }
```