# How to use Session in SignalR Hub class? ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

**How to use Session in SignalR Hub class? ASP.NET MVC**

Here is my code:

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
   if (HttpContext.Current.Session["US_ID"] != null)
   {
      lstUsers.Add(Context.ConnectionId, new USER { US_ID = HttpContext.Current.Session["US_ID"].ToString() });
      Clients.All.BroadcastConnections(lstUsers);
   }
   return base.OnConnected();
}
```

**Error:** Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Error in this line `if (HttpContext.Current.Session["US_ID"] != null)`

**How to solve it?**

Comment: [No access to the Session information through SignalR Hub. Is my design is wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20522477/no-access-to-the-session-information-through-signalr-hub-is-my-design-is-wrong) as discussed before and mentioned in the  [documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1#session-state) you can't.

Comment: I ask for other solutions, because my completed project already use session, I just modify project add signalR.

Comment: What you can do is setting a cookie before opening hub connection. And read that cookie from Context in hub class.

Comment: Okay thank you, I will try it.

Comment: Another option can be to pass it into the hub via querystring. Like so; $.connection.hub.qs = { 'US_ID' : 'test' };

Comment: There is also `Context.User` (`Context.User.Identity.Name`), that can help if you need the currently logged-in user id.